# Is WebRTC still leaking my IP addresses in incognito or private browsing mode?

Tags: web-browser, vpn, vulnerability, webrtc

WebRTC *can* leak your private IP address, even though you are using a VPN, from what I learn [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82129/what-is-webrtc-and-how-can-i-protect-myself-against-leaking-information-that-doe).

Am I protected against this information leak affecting my privacy, when I'm using the incognito or private browsing mode in my browser along with a VPN connection? In other words, is my private IP address hidden from the websites I visit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately both internal and external IP addresses are still exposed even when you're browsing in incognito/private mode. In your case not only your internal network IP-address and the internal VPN IP-address will be exposed but also the external ISP IP address.

You can test it for example here:

<del>https://ipleak.net/</del> (seems offline)
https://www.browserleaks.com/webrtc

Chrome and Firefox leak this information even in incognito/private mode. Although there is a fix:

**For Firefox**

https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/happy-bonobo-disable-webrtc/

**For Google Chrome**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webrtc-leak-prevent/eiadekoaikejlgdbkbdfeijglgfdalml?hl=en

Comment: Sadly, WebRTC does not expose only the local and VPN public IP addresses, but also the user's ISP provided public address *behind* the VPN (the very address you try to hide using the VPN). See for instance [this page](https://www.perfect-privacy.com/webrtc-leaktest/) (or search words like "webrtc stun vpn" in your favorite search engine for more references).

Comment: @WhiteWinterWolf good call, I changed the answer.